# Самый простой вопрос в php

Tags: php

Есть:

```
fwrite($file,trim($_POST['banadd'])."\r\n");
```

Мне нужно присоединить к `$_POST['banadd']` еще и `$_POST['nick']` - как это сделать?

Comment: Это печально ...

Comment: Зайди на какой нибудь ресурс посвящённый PHP и почитай про строки: [тыц](http://php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?string "вот") и [тыдыц](http://php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?string2#str "тыдыц")

Answer (score 4):

```
fwrite($file,trim($_POST['banadd']) . trim($_POST['nick']) ."\r\n");
```

В php точка это конкатенация (склеивание) строки

Comment: строки сольются, а нужен еще пробел
fwrite($file,trim($_POST['banadd']) .' '. trim($_POST['nick']) ."\r\n");

Answer (score 0):

Код, чтобы конкатенировать (соединить) с пробелом:

```php
fwrite($file,trim($_POST['banadd']) . ' ' . trim($_POST['nick']) ."\r\n");
```

Почитайте о конкатенации в PHP [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).